# Performance tuning for extractvalue in oracle 10g

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

There is an XML file (20MB), when i try to extract the values using the select statement from the table using the EXTRACTVALUE its taking a very long time(Hrs). 
The table contains the XML_DATA as XMLTYPE
Please suggest me to tune the SQL QUERY OR any other alternative to extract the values from the large xml file

```
SELECT EXTRACTVALUE (VALUE (Name),'*/Name') FirstName,  
.....   
FROM TB_XML_type,TABLE (XMLSEQUENCE (EXTRACT (xml_data, '*/Name'))) Name
```

**Note :** The XML format is user defined.

Comment: For that size XML document I would consider using SAX.  DOM doesn't cope at all well with that size of document.  Sadly, most (if not all) PL/SQL XML APIs are DOM-based, so you may well have to use a Java stored procedure or move the XML processing outside of the database.  Here's a example of how to use a Java stored procedure to parse an XML document as SAX, which you might be able to adapt: https://forums.oracle.com/message/1389286#1389286.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion . I will try out using Java store procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Setting up a table like yours:

```
CREATE TABLE TB_XML_TYPE(XML_DATA XMLTYPE);

INSERT INTO TB_XML_TYPE(XML_DATA) 
VALUES (XMLTYPE('<a><Name>name1</Name><Name>name2</Name></a>'));
```

I am guessing the Name element is right under the root element in your XML. If that's the case, this may be faster.

```
SELECT XD.NAME FROM TB_XML_TYPE XT, 
    XMLTABLE('/a/Name' PASSING XT.XML_DATA
        COLUMNS NAME VARCHAR2(100) PATH 'text()') XD
```

Result:

```
NAME                                                                                               
---------------------
name1                                                                                                
name2
```

If not, make sure the *repeated* path is right after XMLTABLE - this is the XPath that finds all the parent elements whose children you then read with the XPath right after the PATH keyword. In this case, text() reads the text contents of the Name element.

Comment: I have tried with the XMLTABLE syntax also, but still it takes the same time to execute the query as it was with earlier syntax.

Comment: I have tried with the XMLTABLE syntax also, but still it takes the same time to execute the query as it was with earlier syntax.